# On CentOS 6, how to let user-created files inherit permissions from their parent directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, centos6, file-permissions

So our servers are set-up like this:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnUXM.jpg)

`/asic` is our grand project's folder, `/200T` is a subproject of that grand project, and folders right under `/200T` such as `/lbh` are each worker's personal directories who are working on the subproject. `/asic`, `/200T`, `/lbh` were all created by `root` and then had their properties reconfigured by root via `chmod -R` and `chown -R`. `/asic` and `/200T` are owned by `root` and belongs to groups `asic` and `200T` respectively, while `/lbh` is owned by the worker's user account `lbh` and belongs to group `asic`.

The idea is that content within `/asic` and `/200T` can be seen by all personell working on `asic` and `200T` yet they cannot have write access to these 2 directories-- if they want to create something, they'll have to do that within their own directories (`/lbh` and the like). When a worker creates something in their own directory, we want other workers of the same sub-project to be able to read that new thing, but not modify it by accident. For example, `lbh` just created a file `testbench.v` and a folder `/results` under `/asic/200T/lbh`. Another person (`glj`) on the `200T` subproject should be able to read `/asic/200T/lbh/testbench.v` and `/asic/200T/lbh/results` but not write into them. If `glj` wants to modify them, he'll have to copy them to his own directory `/asic/200T/glj` and then do so.

To achieve the goals above, we need the permissions of directories created by `lbh` to be `drwxr-s---` and files to be `rwxr-s---` by default, however the reality looks like this:
[Files and folders created by lbh and root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJdXF.jpg)

Resulting in each worker being able to write into everyone's own folders and files, which is exactly what we're trying to avoid. The `umask` of `root` is `0022`, and the `umask` of normal users is `0002`.

My questions:

1. Why are the files created by users (like `/lbh`) under their personal directories (like `lbh`) ignoring the `drwxr-s---`
   permission of the personal folder and defaulting to
   `(d)rwxrwsr-x`?
2. Is there safe method to let workers create files and folders
   with (d)rwxr-s--- by default? Asking every user to manually
   `chmod` everything every time is too much of a hassle, and I'm
   worried that changing the default `umask` value can lead to new
   surprise issues down the line.

Thanks a lot!

---

Edit:
The folder structure and permission of files created by lbh and root look like this:

```
[lbh@<machine> lbh]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-s---. 4 lbh  200T 4096 Oct  1 02:40 .
drwxr-sr-x. 4 root 200T 4096 Oct  1 02:18 ..
drwxrwsr-x. 2 lbh  200T 4096 Oct  1 02:26 aaa_lbh
drwxr-sr-x. 2 root 200T 4096 Oct  1 02:26 aaa_root
-rw-rw-r--. 1 lbh  200T    0 Oct  1 02:38 file_lbh.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root 200T    0 Oct  1 02:40 file_root.txt
[lbh@<machine> lbh]$ pwd
/asic/200T/lbh
[lbh@<machine> lbh]$ cd ..
[lbh@<machine> 200T]$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-sr-x. 4 root 200T 4096 Oct  1 02:18 .
drwxr-x---. 3 root asic 4096 Oct  1 02:16 ..
drwxr-sr-x. 2 root 200T 4096 Oct  1 02:18 aaa
drwxr-s---. 4 lbh  200T 4096 Oct  1 02:40 lbh
[lbh@<machine> 200T]$ pwd
/asic/200T
[lbh@<machine> 200T]$
```

And `getfacl`results of directories and files are as follows:

```
[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic
# owner: root
# group: asic
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/
# owner: root
# group: 200T
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/lbh
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/lbh
# owner: lbh
# group: 200T
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/lbh/aaa_lbh/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/lbh/aaa_lbh/
# owner: lbh
# group: 200T
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/lbh/aaa_root/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/lbh/aaa_root/
# owner: root
# group: 200T
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/lbh/file_lbh.txt 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/lbh/file_lbh.txt
# owner: lbh
# group: 200T
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl /asic/200T/lbh/file_root.txt 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: asic/200T/lbh/file_root.txt
# owner: root
# group: 200T
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ touch hello.txt
[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ mkdir hi 
[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 lbh lbh 4096 Oct  9 17:28 .
drwx------. 36 lbh lbh 4096 Oct  9 17:21 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 lbh lbh    0 Oct  9 17:27 hello.txt
drwxrwxr-x.  2 lbh lbh 4096 Oct  9 17:28 hi
[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl hi
# file: hi
# owner: lbh
# group: lbh
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$ getfacl hello.txt 
# file: hello.txt
# owner: lbh
# group: lbh
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--

[lbh@<machine> Desktop]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't support permission inheritance, so you can't do what you asked in the question topic.

The best you can do is to set *default POSIX ACL* which will apply to all newly created files and directories. This is not the inheritance, just the default:

```
setfacl -m default:user:<username>:rwx <dir>
setfacl -m default:group:<groupname>:rwx <dir>
```

After this, if anybody creates a file or directory in  (if they are allowed to create objects there, of course), that object will get additional ACL `user:<username>:rwx` and `group:<groupname>:rwx`. You can set default permissions for owner and group-owner by setting `<username>` and `<groupname>` blank.

This "default" could only be set upon a directory, because there is no point to apply this to files. Permissions set this way also get masked with umasks, so if some bit is dropped in umask, this bit will be dropped from a permission. For instance, when you create a file, if you don't give it executable bit, it wouldn't be made executable (as expected). Created subdirectories will also have the same "default" ACLs set, so its descendants will have these ACLs set too. You have to remove or change ACLs on subdirectories after creation to stop this propagation.

Check the ACL with `getfacl <dir>`. Of course, there could be several such defaults (and it seems you have to end up with several rules); at least, requirements that I encountered always mandated the presence of at least two default group ACLs).

---

You *can not* set "default file owners" this way, the owner will always be set to creating process effective uid. By default, group-owner will be set to process gid, but you can change that by using the *setgid* bit on the parent directory:

```
    chmod g+s <dir>
```

after that, any object created in that directory will copy its group-owner by default, even if creating user doesn't belong to that group. This setgit bit propagates to subdirectories.

Owners can set group-owner to any group that they belong to. If they don't belong to the group derived by setgid, they can change their file group-owner to any group they belong to, but after that they won't be able to change it back into setgid value.

---

I want to note again explicitely, this is *not* an inheritance, this is setting defaults which is not exactly the same. If you change something on parent object afterwards, already created objects will always retain their permissions in Linux.

While, for example, in Windows, when you set sub-object ACLs to "inherit", changing parent ACLs will affect descendants, which is the proper inheritance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try to see if this method works well enough for us. Though I'm still confused about why user-created folders are drwxrwsr-x? A umask value of 0022 should make it drwxrwxr-x, right? So is the gid bit inherited?

Comment: Correction: sorry I meant a umask value of 0002 (normal user), not 0022 (root)

Comment: *nothing* is inherited. Default ACLs are saved as ACL, umask is set as file modes, and then if somebody accesses the file Linux reads both and ANDs them calculate actual permission.

Comment: So in my second screenshot ("Files and folders created by lbh and root") the folder "aaa_lbh" created by lbh is drwxrwsr-x instead of drwxrwxr-x, and that "s" is there because Linux calculated both lbh's umask and the parent folder's (/asic/200T/lbh) ACL?

Comment: Doesn't "s" mean "setgid"? It doesn't have anything in common with these masks. But I must admit I forgot about this possibility. It allows descendants to derive owner-group from the directory instead of process gid. If you want to explore ACLs, use `getfacl`, it also caclulates effective permissions. And, finally, all of this is *textual* information, please, don't take screenshots, copy and paste the console output instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my original post with terminal outputs. New files created by ```lbh``` on ```Desktop``` do not have the ```setgid``` bit, so it seems new files created under ```/asic/200T/lbh``` do have the ```s``` flag because the parent directory does.